# HTML stuck at page 1 python

Tags: python, html, ubuntu, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to build a webscraper for a given webpage with `requests` and `lxml.html`packages.

When I trying to iterate over its pages, it seems like I always get the html of the first page. Ideally I would like to retrieve the content of the main table of each page and store it in a pandas df.

Any suggestion where my code is failing? I am working with python 3.7.4 and Ubuntu OS

```
import requests
import lxml.html as lh
import pandas as pd

base_url = "https://etfdb.com/etfs/asset-class/#etfs&sort_name=assets_under_management&sort_order=desc&page="

n_pages = 15
data = []
for i in range(1,n_pages+1):
    url = base_url+str(i)            
    page = requests.get(url)    
    doc = lh.fromstring(page.content)

    # Retrieve all tr_like elements (table rows)
    tr_elements = doc.xpath('//tr') 

    #Create a columns vector to create our df
    col = list(filter(None,tr_elements[0].text_content().split("\n")))

    #Iterate over the rows of the table
    for j in range(1,len(tr_elements)-1):
        row = tr_elements[j]

        #Since there are multiple tables in the webpage, make sure
        #we are retrieving the rows of the correct one
        if len(row)==len(col):
            data.append([value.text_content() for value in row.iterchildren()])
        else:
            print("Ignoring data")

df =  pd.DataFrame(data,columns=col)
```

Comment: I don't see that you're doing anything either with _page_ or with _doc_. Can you include the rest of the code?

Comment: Like @Dinac23 said. If you want to get **another** page you need to make **another** `requests.get`  you are not doing this. Btw your code is not reproducible please provide the rest.

Comment: @Dinac23 I have just updated the code, I missed a part. I am changing the url dynamically in the for loop, shouldn't that update "page" and "doc" variables?

Comment: @eusoubrasileiro I have just updated the code, I missed a part. I am changing the url dynamically in the for loop, shouldn't that update "page" and "doc" variables?

Comment: @AxelBorasinoDiBola it seams that page is the problem. I plain simple `GET` will not work on it. Try using inspect on `Google chrome` or `Firefox` to see the request headers your browser is generating and work from that.

Comment: Even though you change the page via URL, the actual content of the page source stays the same and there's an AJAX call in the background that gets the new data and populates the table. Your best bet would be to get the data using [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/index.html).

Comment: @Dinac23 Thanks for your contribution Dinac23! I will give a try with Selenium and in case I solve it, I will post the solution here.

Answer (score 0):

add some delay after this line `page = requests.get(url)`, requests library takes some time to get the page content but loop is executing faster than that

Comment: Delaying does nothing, requests.get is a synchronous operation so the code execution will stop until we receive a response .

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with the code, but the website itself. You can't **scrape** those tables like the way you are doing now because those tables are asynchronous templates and they are taking time to load the actual table with the page number you expect.

Lets say,load the url with page value 5 - first it's loading the table with page 1 data and then loading the table with the page 5 data

Try to understand how the tables with those url's values are loading, you can notice the same.

I don't think we can fix something in your code to accomplish this, use `selenium` it's hepful in these scenarios.

Please correct me in case I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

After some research and time,I finally could scrape the page with Selenium. Even though there are a couple of not very elegant workarounds (e.g wait fixed number of seconds to load the page or retrieve native HTML for some fields) the code retrieves the fields successfully in the n columns of the desired table along multiple pages (specified by the user). Finally, a data frame is created with all the info.(This is using Python 3.6 version and Ubuntu OS)

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
import time

values = {}
delay = 10 # seconds
n_pages = 10
for i in range(1,n_pages):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    url = 'https://etfdb.com/etfs/asset-class/#etfs&sort_name=assets_under_management&sort_order=desc&page='
    page = url+str(i)
    driver.get(page)

    # After doing the query, wait delay seconds until is fully loaded
    time.sleep(delay)

    # Retrieve all rows excep the header and bottom
    table_id = driver.find_element_by_class_name('fixed-table-body')
    rows = table_id.find_elements_by_tag_name('tr')[1:-1]
    for row in rows:
        fields = row.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')
        ticker = fields[0].text
        name = fields[1].text
        ass_class,aum = fields[2].text,fields[3].text[1:]

        # For some reason I don't know, get_attribute text delivered
        # blank results for the two following fields, that is why
        # I needed to retrieve the innerHTML and parse it from there
        etf_category = fields[19].get_attribute("innerHTML").split('>')[1].split('<')[0].strip().lower()
        er = float(fields[21].get_attribute("innerHTML")[:-1])

        # Populate the dict
        values[ticker] = {'name':name,'asset_class':ass_class,'Total_Assets(MM$)':aum,\
                          'ETF_category':etf_category,'Expense_ratio':er}
    # Close the url once it's been scraped   
    driver.quit()

# Create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(values).T
```

Answer (score -1):

I have just modified your code to make it work, please check:-

```
import requests
import lxml.html as lh
import pandas as pd

base_url = "https://etfdb.com/etfs/asset-class/#etfs&sort_name=assets_under_management&sort_order=desc&page="

data = []
final_url = []

for r in range(1,16): #change the upper range as per requirement
    final_url.append(base_url + str(r))
for url in final_url:     
    page = requests.get(url)    
    doc = lh.fromstring(page.content)

    # Retrieve all tr_like elements (table rows)
    tr_elements = doc.xpath('//tr') 

    #Create a columns vector to create our df
    col = list(filter(None,tr_elements[0].text_content().split("\n")))

    #Iterate over the rows of the table
    for j in range(1,len(tr_elements)-1):
        row = tr_elements[j]

        #Since there are multiple tables in the webpage, make sure
        #we are retrieving the rows of the correct one
        if len(row)==len(col):
            data.append([value.text_content() for value in row.iterchildren()])
        else:
            print("Ignoring data")

df =  pd.DataFrame(data,columns=col)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but this does not solve the error. If you check df you'll see that there is only the first 25 rows of the first page repeated 15 times.